# Kendo UI DatePicker Javascript and HttpContext.Session C#, MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

We are using a Kendo UI date picker (Javascript version), in which I want to populate with an HttpContext.Session variable that has a date passed from our KendoUI datepicker and passed to our controller, Session is set in the controller.

The KendoUI DatePicker is used on multiple pages in multiple templates.
My goal is to have the date selected and set in Session be passed back to the KendoUI DatePicker if the variable is set. And if the date selected is not set, I want the Date Picker's value to be set to today or new Date().

My Javascript:

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

    var SelectedDate = new Date();
 //Is this even correct?
    if('@HttpContext.Current.Session["CalendarSelectedDate"]' != '@DateTime.Now'){
        SelectedDate == '@HttpContext.Current.Session["CalendarSelectedDate"]';
        console.log("In if");
    }else{
        SelectedDate == new Date();
        console.log("In else");
    }
    console.log('Selected date: ' + SelectedDate);

   // WANT TO SET VALUE FROM SESSION DATE HERE!!!
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
        value: SelectedDate,
        min: new Date(),
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
        change: function () {
            var value = this.value();
            console.log(value); //value is the selected date in the datepicker
            initialGetEventTypes();
        }
    });
    initialGetEventTypes();
});
  </script>

  //The AJAX call to the controller
  <script type="text/javascript">

function initialGetEventTypes() {
     @{ 
         var dateFromHub = DateTime.Now;
         var obj = HttpContext.Current.Session["CalendarSelectedDate"];
         if(obj != null)
         {
             dateFromHub = Convert.ToDateTime(obj);
         }
     }

    console.log('Session Selected Date: @dateFromHub.ToShortDateString()');
    $('#categoryLoading').show();
    var startDateTime = $("#datepicker").val();
    var endDateTime = startDateTime;
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetTotalEventTypeIdsByDate", "MuseumUniversalCalendar")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { startDateTime: startDateTime, endDateTime: endDateTime },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#categoryLoading').hide();
                $('.product-item').find('.categoryAvaiableCapacity').html("Not Available");
                var list = JSON.stringify(data);
                $("#eventTypeName").find('option').remove().end();
                $.each(data.result, function (i, eventTypes) {
                        $('.product-item').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).attr('data-galaxyeventnamefromnop') == eventTypes.EventName) {
                                $(this).find('.categoryAvaiableCapacity').html(eventTypes.Available + ' Available');
                           }
                        });
                    });

                if (data.result.length === 0)  {
     $("#noEvents").text('@T("museum.noeventavailablemessage")');

                }else{
                    // console.log("we are here")
                    $("#noEvents").text("");
                }

            },
            error: function(xhr, error, data) {
                console.log(xhr, error, data);
                $('#categoryLoading').hide();
                $("#eventTypeName").find('option').remove().end();
                alert("An error occurred getting the Event Types");
            }
        });
   }

</script>
```

My Controller method:

```
  public class MuseumUniversalCalendarController : Controller
{
    //[NonAction]
     public JsonResult GetTotalEventTypeIdsByDate(MuseumUniversalCalendarModel model, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime)
    {
        //Set selected Date for session
        HttpContext.Session["CalendarSelectedDate"] = startDateTime;

        var result = eventListOfEvents(model, startDateTime, endDateTime);
        return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public List<cEvent> eventListOfEvents(MuseumUniversalCalendarModel model, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime)
    {
        var eventTypeIdList = ExternalDataAccess.HubServiceCalls.GetAvailableEventsByEventDate(startDateTime, endDateTime);

        foreach(var eventTypeItem in eventTypeIdList)
        {
            model.AvailableGalaxyEventTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = eventTypeItem.EventName,
                Value = eventTypeItem.EventTypeId.ToString()
            });
        }

        var fullOutEventlist = eventTypeIdList;
        var totalsList = eventTypeIdList.GroupBy(e => e.EventName.ToString()).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
        totalsList.ForEach(x => x.Available = eventTypeIdList.Where(y => y.EventName == x.EventName).Select(z => z.Available).Sum());
        return totalsList;
    }
```

Comment: If the date picked has session scope, why not just inject the value on page_init? https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+inject+javascript&ie=&oe=

Comment: This is MVC, there is no page_init.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the datapicker in a partial view that can read the session value out into the view's JS with razor. You could even isolate it to its own controller.

Views/Shared/_DatePickPartial.cshtml

```
<div id='datepicker'></div>
<script>
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: '@HttpContext.Session["CalendarSelectedDate" ] ?? new Date()',
    min: new Date(),
    format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
    change: function () {
         //send ajax to partial action DatePickPartialUpdate which will add value to session
    }
});
</script>
```

SomeController _DatePickPartial

```
public ActionResult _DatePickPartialUpdate(DateTime2 value)
{
    Session["CalendarSelectedDate"] = value;
}
```